# Android app which asks for a password when other selected app clicked by user

Tags: java, android

i am new in android and I would like to ask if there is any way how can my app check which other app is being clicked by user and if the other app is selected in settings then my app can ask for a password for example, I did not manage to find much about this and there are some apps on play store like applock that do this. If somebody could at least point me to right direction , would be appreciated , thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "if the other app is selected in settings then my app can ask for a password for example"

Comment: the best example I can make is the Applock app on play store where you can lock all apps you have installed, if you tap this locked app you will be asked for a password which you did set in the Applock, and  my question is how can I see from inside my app if user is not taping other apps and if locked also display some view where password should be inserted